# apt-get install kubuntu-desktop failed - trying to overwrite

Tags: apt, kubuntu

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
...
Unpacking kaccounts-providers (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kaccounts-providers_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/signon-ui/webkit-options.d/www.facebook.com.conf', which is also in package account-plugin-facebook 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kaccounts-providers_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried again:

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.338).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried that:

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblept5 liblightdm-qt-3-0
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
259 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 518857 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I deleted it:

```
root@gcomputer:~# rm -rf /usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service
```

But still the same:

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get install -f
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried to remove the `account-plugin-google` package:

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get purge account-plugin-google
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-gdrive : Depends: account-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to proceed from there. This seems somewhat non-intuitive.

...

I thought that maybe `aptitude` is more clever and tries to help me more. So I tried:

```
root@gcomputer:~# aptitude remove account-plugin-google
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  account-plugin-google liblept5{u} liblightdm-qt-3-0{u} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
... (a lot)
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 2571 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-scope-gdrive : Depends: account-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed.
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                               
1)      kde-telepathy                                              
2)      kde-telepathy-minimal                                      
3)      unity-scope-gdrive                                         

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                 
4)      unity-lens-files recommends unity-scope-gdrive             
5)      unity-lens-photos recommends account-plugin-google         
6)      kde-telepathy-approver recommends kde-telepathy            
7)      kde-telepathy-auth-handler recommends kde-telepathy        
8)      kde-telepathy-contact-list recommends kde-telepathy        
9)      kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler recommends kde-telepathy
10)     kde-telepathy-integration-module recommends kde-telepathy  
11)     kde-telepathy-send-file recommends kde-telepathy           
12)     kde-telepathy-text-ui recommends kde-telepathy             
13)     kubuntu-desktop recommends kde-telepathy                   
14)     mcp-account-manager-uoa recommends account-plugin-google   
15)     unity recommends unity-scope-gdrive                        


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]   (I typed Y. Not sure but I hope the best.)
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  account-plugin-google kde-telepathy{a} kde-telepathy-approver{u} kde-telepathy-auth-handler{u} kde-telepathy-contact-list{u} 
  kde-telepathy-data{u} kde-telepathy-desktop-applets{u} kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler{u} kde-telepathy-integration-module{u} 
  kde-telepathy-minimal{a} kde-telepathy-send-file{u} kde-telepathy-text-ui{u} libktpmodels9{u} libktpotr9{u} libktpwidgets9{u} liblept5{u} 
  liblightdm-qt-3-0{u} qml-module-org-kde-telepathy{u} unity-scope-gdrive{a} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
... (again a lot...)
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 19 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 8489 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]   (I typed Y.)
(Reading database ... 518855 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing kde-telepathy (15.04.20ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-minimal (15.04.20ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-approver (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-auth-handler (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-contact-list (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-text-ui (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-send-file (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-desktop-applets (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-integration-module (4:15.12.1-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing qml-module-org-kde-telepathy (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libktpwidgets9 (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libktpmodels9 (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libktpotr9 (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing unity-scope-gdrive (0.9+16.04.20151125-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing account-plugin-google (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblept5 (1.73-1) ...
Removing liblightdm-qt-3-0:amd64 (1.18.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-telepathy-data (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Current status: 0 (-1) broken.
```

So, that seems to have done something. Not sure if it was fine. The final message is a bit confusing. 0 (-1) broken == 0 (+1) fixed?

I wanted to check with `apt-get` again:

```
root@gcomputer:~# apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.338).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kaccounts-integration kde-telepathy-kaccounts kde-telepathy-kpeople libkaccounts1 libktpcommoninternals9 libktplogger9 libtelepathy-logger-qt5
  libtelepathy-qt5-0 signon-kwallet-extension telepathy-accounts-signon
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I still wonder about these kde-telepathy things. They are optional? I don't have them now? They are broken?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
sudo find /var/cache -name "kde-config-telepathy-accounts*"
```

Sample output

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Install it with flag --force-overwrite as shown below:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Finally, run the following command to complete KDE plasma installation.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `clean` before running `-f install`

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt -f install
```

Today this help me to solve the stuck while installing `kubuntu-desktop` over my `ubuntu-desktop` notebook.

The help was found on Russian Ubuntu forum
http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=291122.0